# What are these libs showed by brew doctor?

Tags: macos, homebrew

```
Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libappfirewall.a
/usr/local/lib/libautoblock.a
/usr/local/lib/libautosetup.a
/usr/local/lib/libconnectionsclient.a
/usr/local/lib/liblocationawareness.a
/usr/local/lib/libpersonalfirewall.a
/usr/local/lib/libtrustedcomponents.a
```

when I did a `brew doctor`, I googled and found no clues.  Is my Mac affected by some virus?  Does anyone know where does these libs come from? Can I remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the `strings` output of a few of the files, it looks like they're part of the Symantec Endpoint Protection suite. I imagine they're pretty similar if you're using Norton Internet Security.

`# strings /usr/local/lib/libautoblock.a | grep -i symantec
SymAutoBlockRegisterSettings caught exception!  Some Symantec settings may be inaccessible.`